# Adding an ActionBar to the Default Google Maps Activity Template in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-studio, android-actionbar

I've been able to add all of my markers to my map, using locations provided by my API, but I've been unable to add an ActionBar.

As mentioned, I am using the Android Studio "Google Maps Activity" template. How can I go about adding an ActionBar to this template?

Please let me know if there's any code that you need from me.

Comment: The default template already displays an ActionBar in my case..

Comment: @user3249477 Hmm... The template itself gives the impression it would have an actionbar, but when I actually build the project, nothing.

Comment: This information about your app might help: minSdk, targetSdk, activity style and device API version.

Comment: @user3249477 minsdk: 18, target sdk: 21, theme: Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar, and device API version 19. Thank you!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Extending `AppCompatActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity` helped me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The current accepted answer does not solve this problem!!

Comment: Agreed @pedroremedios! This solution worked for me. I will flag the other answer that was originally accepted which did not work.

Comment: Works for me, by changing `FragmentActivity` to `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: Along with this, placing the toolbar after MapFragment in Layout file worked for me. If Toolbar is before MapFragment, map sits on top of it and hides the toolbar

Answer (score 2):

Since your minSdk is 18, you shouldn't be using the support theme (`AppCompat`). Change it to holo:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>
```

Also make sure your activities extend `Activity` or `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: my activity extends `FragmentActivity` and `miniSDK` is `15` what to do. when I try `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Holo">
</style>` android studio give no suggestions.

Comment: I have all of the above mentioned, but this solution did not work for me. However, the solution from @GeorgeK on this page of changing **extends FragmentActivity** to **AppCompatActivity** fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I followed this example https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html and I changed my coordinator layout to relative layout so that I could position my map fragment and other buttons below the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `MapsActivity` extends the `FragmentActivity`, **which does not have the `getSupportActionBar` method.**

##### Instead, make sure that your `MapsActivity` extends `AppCompatActivity`.

It worked for me and had no consequences at all in my code.